# What is the use of ArrayList<ArrayList<E>>

Tags: java, collections

Can you give any reasonable example for a `ArrayList<ArrayList<E>>`, such as declaring, initializing, adding elements and iterating them. Is this one of the way to get 2-dimensional Array behavior in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, an `ArrayList<ArrayList<E>>` is similar to a two-dimensional array of `E` (`E[][]`). It has all the common differences between using a `List` and using arrays in Java (`List` is a higher-level API, supports resizing, adding elements at arbitrary positions, ...).

You don't treat it any different from a normal `List`, except that the elements it contains are actually other `List` objects:

- Initialize it:

  ```
  ArrayList<ArrayList<E>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<E>>();
  ```
- Iterate over it:

  ```
  for (ArrayList<E> innerList : listOfLists) {
    doSomethingWithInnerList(innerList);
  }
  ```
- Add to it:

  ```
  ArrayList<E> newInnerList = new ArrayList<E>();
  // add stuff to newInnerList
  listOfLists.add(newInnerList);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I want to add to Joachim Sauer's answer is that yes, an `ArrayList<ArrayList<E>>` *can* be similar to a two-dimensional array of E (`E[][]`) with one additional twist (in addition to all the usual differences between one-dimensional arrays and lists):

Using a list of lists, you can make the equivalent of a "jagged" array. Not all of the inner lists need to have the same `size()`, whereas in a two-dimensional array, all of the "rows" of `E[][]` by definition have identical lengths. It's "rectangular". A list of lists doesn't have to be rectangular; it can be jagged.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is used to hold array of objects. On the other it can have duplicate values. when you need a fast insertion/deletion you can use it. it holds the values in the same order as it is entered into it. For example

```
List<String> ls= new ArrayList<String>();
ls.add("foo");
ls.add("bar");
for(String val:ls){
    System.out.println("Value :" + val);
}
```